# Rounded inner shadow at the top and bottom of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is what I would like to achieve :

[image]

A UITableView with rounded inner shadows at the top and the bottom

I have currently no idea how to create these shadows only at the top and the bottom and then how to make them round.

Or maybe it would be easier to create two UIViews with radial gradients and transparent background.

**Does anyone have any experience with the same kind of thing ?**

Comment: put an image at the top and bottom of the table and fade it out when you're on the first or last cell.

Comment: Just add the shadow as a transparent png file as a subview in the table. Simple as that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't even think of that. I'll give it a try a update the post or add an answer.